# Using grep can't find exact match when string contains parentheses ()

Tags: r, regex, string, grepl

I have the following df

```
A                                                                          B
"Axon guidance"                                                            1                                                                                                
"Chemical carcinogenesis - reactive oxygen species"                        2                                                           
"Electron Transport Chain (OXPHOS system in mitochondria)"                 3                                                                                                                                           
"The citric acid (TCA) cycle and respiratory electron transport"           4
```

Using

```
 grep(paste0("^", df[3,1], "$"), df[,1]))
```

Gives 0

Using

```
 grep(paste0("^", df[2,1], "$"), df[,1]))
```

Finds the exact match (integer which is the line containing the match)

Why grep can't get an exact match when using with strings that contains parentheses?

Comment: Parentheses have a special meaning inside regular expressions as used by `grep`. If you want exact matches, used the argument `fixed = TRUE` inside `grep`

Comment: By default `grep()` uses regular expressions, and parentheses have special meaning there.  You could use `fixed = TRUE` if you're willing to drop the begin `"^"` and end `"$"` markers, but if all you want is an exact match, why not use `"=="`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted, the problem here is that round brackets are control characters used to define capture groups in RegEx search patterns.

Two approaches you may wish to consider are:

1. Sanitise the text being searched and the text used to create search patterns of the relevant characters
2. Double escape the RegEx control characters in the search patterns

### Generate Sample Data

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("Axon guidance", 
                     "Chemical carcinogenesis - reactive oxygen species", 
                     "Electron Transport Chain (OXPHOS system in mitochondria)",
                     "The citric acid (TCA) cycle and respiratory electron transport"),
                 B=1:4)
```

#### Demonstrate problem

```
grep(paste0("^", df[2,1], "$"), df[,1]) # <- the OP has an extra bracket here
grep(paste0("^", df[3,1], "$"), df[,1])
```

### Option 1

Here we sanitise both the text being searched & the patterns used to search

Here we are just sanitising for round brackets but there are other special
characters in regex (and cases where complex unicode characters also create
problems)

```
df$sanitised_text <- gsub("[()]*", "", df$A)
```

#### Demonstrate Solution

```
grep(paste0("^", df[2, "sanitised_text"], "$"), df[,"sanitised_text"]) 
grep(paste0("^", df[3,"sanitised_text"], "$"), df[,"sanitised_text"])
```

### Option 2 - Double escape the regex control characters

```
sanitise_search_patterns <- function(x){
  y <- gsub("\\(", "\\\\(", x)
  gsub("\\)", "\\\\)", y)
}
 
df$sanitised_search_patterns <- sanitise_search_patterns(df$A)
```

#### Demonstrate Solution

```
grep(paste0("^", df[2, "sanitised_search_patterns"], "$"), df[,"A"]) 
grep(paste0("^", df[3,"sanitised_search_patterns"], "$"), df[,"A"])
```

You could use either approach here but there are cases where non-control characters can create similar types of false negatives - e.g. a multiplicity of unicode characters for whitespace, hyphens and complex characters formed from more than one glyph - so sanitising the search text might still be usefully considered alongside double escaping.

Answer (score 2):

Because parentheses needs double backlashes to be matched as such in R. Otherwise they are understood as [special characters](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/NEWS/regexp.html).

```r
grep(paste0("\\)$"), df[,1])
#[1] 3
```

As stated in the comments, you could also `fixed = TRUE` in the `grep` function to match the string as is

```r
grep(df[3,1], df[,1], fixed = TRUE)
#[1] 3
```

---

To find an exact matching you can simply use `which`:

```r
which(df[,1] == df[3,1])
```

Comment: Using fixed = TRUE still finds matches that are not completly equal. For example "A lovely fox" and "A lovely fox walking in the snow", if you try to match "A lovely fox", both will be found. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Yes, using the anchors (^ and $), as you are doing. Or just using `==`, like `which(df[, 1] == "x")`

Comment: I can`t use anchors because of the special characters! But using == works